# How to match a specific email with RegEx

Tags: asp.net, regex, email

I want to extend the standard asp.net email regex validator to exclude a specific email.

This is the original:

```
 ValidationExpression="(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)"
```

This is the extended that I produced:

```
 ValidationExpression="(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)|(?!^email\@email\.com$)"
```

Can't figure out why this doesn't work

*P.s. I know that the standard asp.net regex validator is not recommended for email validation, but it is OK for me.*

Comment: I don't know ASP, but your snippet seems to miss a closing `)` at the end before the `"`

Comment: I don't know ASP, but regex is not a tool for matching **specific** strings. Can't you create a black list of some sort? P.S. Isn't that an OR between the initial pattern and the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!^email@email\.com$)[originalregexhere]
```

This is doing a negative lookahead right at the beginning of the matching.

The full example:

```
ValidationExpression="(?!^email@email\.com$)(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work as the first part of your pattern matches so it doesn't use your negated second part. You are basically checking if *pattern1* **or** *pattern2* matches.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/271946/832273 how to create your own validator. This allows you to do all kind of different checks in your program yourself without the need to put everything into your regex.