# Getting a members Email with asp.net login control

Tags: asp.net, login-control

I am using asp login control.

Ex. getting the name with `<asp:loginName ID="" runat="servet" />`

How is it possible to get the email of the user. Not from code behind?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

To copy the user name to the email address, handle the CreatingUser event and do it there:

protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatingUser( object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e )
    {
        CreateUserWizard1.Email = CreateUserWizard1.UserName;
    }

I'd also recommend adding a [regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182542/email-address-validation-for-asp-net) to validate the email format for the user name.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not making me clear. The only thing I want is a:

Comment: <asp:loginEmail ID="" runat="server" />