# Ajax - validate form on server side

Tags: python, validation, twisted.web

I am writing a simple web that has a form that needs to be validated on server side. After validation, if success, server will redirect to another page, otherwise, there will be an error popup on the current page, keeping all inputted values.

I am thinking of using Ajax but I don't have much experience on this. Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this thread. You will have to work on the redirection though.

[Validate data on server using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523783/call-answer-between-php-and-asp-net/26526427#26526427)

Use this for redirection in javascript,

```
document.location='you/redirect/url'
```